# How to make sure php has write permissions on wp dedicated server

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, file-permissions, mkdir

I have been struggling with this for some time. I moved my wordpress site over from a PRQ domain to a dedicated server. The script is used for picture uploads. I didn't like the folder structure of wordpress by date and instead have a file structure in uploads that places the picture in a subfolder with the post id as the name. This worked just fine on the PRQ domain, but now fails to work on the new server. I am not super knowledgeable about being a server admin, but here is what i have tried.

chown-ing the uploads to the username:apache, apache:apache, nobody:apache, nobody:nobody. I also tried all these combinations up to wp-content and the public_html. all recursively of course.

chmod-ing all the folders to 777, 775, 755, 766.

safe-mode is not running

tried using mkdir and wp_mkdir_p actions.

Restarts on apache throughout just to make sure changes were saved and made.

None of this has any affect.

I have seen a few places that people have suggested getting ahold of the server host to give php writing capabilites. Would I have to do this even though it is a dedicated server that I installed everything on? If not, is there a config or setting I am missing. I see no reason why I can't make a new directory.

WP 3.5.1
php 5.3.3
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
linux os

Comment: Can you create new files in existing directories?

Comment: yes i can create new directories through FTP (using filezilla) but not through putty/ssh console under the user or root.

Answer (score 0):

Check your server logs, you will find your answers there. Blindly trying things doesn't get you out of trouble. Their location should be `/var/log/httpd/` .

Also, i do suspect that permissions is not an issue, but the way your php code acts, maybe you upgraded from php 5.2.x and there's something not working properly in php 5.3.x. Also, turn on wp error reporting from your wp-config.php file(see `WP_DEBUG` i think is called)

Comment: This wasn't blindly trying things. I did a lot of research and was trying the things that others with similar problems with php/wp were having and said worked. The versions of php and wp are identical to what I had before. And the odd thing is that there is no return (failure, error etc.) when I try to run this. not on screen nor in the log. The only difference is now is I'm running redhat instead of ubuntu